# Send multiple Post requests using ajax on button click in the same page

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi I am working on a jsp page, which renders multiple values dynamically and show a button on each value, when i click on each button i should trigger a ajax call which sends that value to the backend.

for example

value1 add

value2 add

when i click on add for value 1 then value 1 should be sending as part of the post request.

i cannot add id's for each element because as this page is a dynamic page.
i have looked some of the stack overflow answers but they are all using ID in their element.

[Please find the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqA6a.png) if you have no idea what i am talking about Please suggest.

The jsp i wrote.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<title>Items List</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to LassiShop </h1>
<c:set var="url" value="/cart"/>
<c:if test="${itemsData.size() gt 0}">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Price</th>
        <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <c:forEach items="${itemsData}" var="item">
      <div class="form">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <c:out value="${item.name}"/>
            <input type="hidden" class="name" value="${item.name}">
          </td>
          <td>
            <c:out value="${item.price}"/>
            <input type="hidden" class="price" value="${item.price}">
           </td>
          <td><input type="number" class="quantity"/></td>
          <td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">ADD TO CART</button></td>
        </tr>
       </div>
      </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${itemsData.size() eq 0}">
    <h3>No Products available for this Category</h3>
</c:if>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('click',".btn",function(){
var itemData = {};
    itemData["name"] = $('.name').text();
    itemData["price"] = $('.price').text();
    itemData["quantity"] = $('.quantity').text();
    console.log(itemData);
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : "/cart",
        data : JSON.stringify(itemData),
        dataType : 'json',
        async:true
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cart", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String testCart(@RequestBody CartEntryData cartEntry){
        System.out.println(cartEntry.getName());
        System.out.println(cartEntry.getPrice());
        System.out.println(cartEntry.getQuantity());
        return "itemsList";
    }
```

Please refer to the picture above to see how my products are getting displayed.

Note here that i cannot use ID since this is dynamic,i need to somehow get the data from the front end & send it to the controller class.

The above jquery doesn't work because the syntax is either false or wrong.

Comment: I don't want you to write code for me but i do want some suggestions. I have updated and posted what i wrote but i don't think that's correct because on the console log i am getting empty objects.

Comment: Ok, that is much better. When you presented no code we had no idea where you were stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues:

1. `<div>` is invalid child of `<tbody>` and invalid parent of `<tr>`.
2. Use `val()` not `text()` to get value from form controls like `<input>`, `<select>` etc.
3. You need the specific row instance of each of the values to send. To do that use `closest()` to isolate the row and `find()` to get the specific element within the row something like:

```
$(document).on('click', ".btn", function() {
  // `this` is the button event occured on
  var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
  
  var itemData = {
    name: $row.find('.name').val(),
    price: $row.find('.price').val(),
    quantity: $row.find('.quantity').val()

  };
  console.log(itemData)
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "/cart",
    data: JSON.stringify(itemData),
    dataType: 'json',
    //async: true  pointless as this is default
  });
});
```

Comment: You are awesome..! i have been searching for this from the past 3 hours, Thank you so much. looks like i need your code after all.